# VBA create gantt chart with day/hour/minute timestamps

Tags: excel, vba, date, shapes, gantt-chart

I am attempting to create a gantt chart from a start timestamp and end timestamp column.

[image]

So far, I have the code that creates the dates as columns with a Zero hour and minute timestamp:
[image]

You will notice that there are lines in the cells where the Start_Timestamp day row value matches the day of the column name.  These are actually compressed rectangles, but what I would like to do is have these rectangles to be expanded to start at the the hour and minute of the Start_Timestamp and end at the hour and minute of the End Timestamp.

Here is an approximation of what I want to do (I did this manually):

[image]

Here is the code that creates my starting calendar:

```
Sub Create_Calendar()
Sheets("Gantt").UsedRange.Delete
Sheets("Triece_Calendar").Columns("A:F").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Gantt").Columns("A:F")
 Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Gantt")

    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.UsedRange) 'Adjust for empty rows/columns
        'Column G is Column 7
        .Range(.Range("G2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7)).Formula = "=INT(B2)+MOD(C2,1)"
        .Columns("G").Calculate 'Make sure the values have calculated
        .Columns("G").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm;@" 'Display in your format
        .Range("G1").Value = "Start_Timestamp"
        .Range(.Range("H2"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8)).Formula = "=INT(D2)+MOD(E2,1)"
        .Columns("H").Calculate 'Make sure the values have calculated
        .Columns("H").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm;@" 'Display in your format
        .Range("H1").Value = "End_Timestamp"
        .Range("B:E").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End With
    Min_Date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Columns("G"))
    Max_Date = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Columns("H"))
    NextDate = Min_Date
    Range("I1").Select
     
    'selection of columns within one row
    Do Until NextDate > Max_Date
        Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm;@"
        ActiveCell.Value = NextDate - TimeSerial(Hour(NextDate), Minute(NextDate), 0)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        NextDate = NextDate + 1
    Loop
    ActiveCell.Value = Max_Date + 1
    ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm;@"
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value - TimeSerial(Hour(Max_Date), Minute(Max_Date), 0)
End Sub
```

And this is the code that I have currently to place my shapes:

```
    Sub Create_Gantt()
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Delete
    Create_Calendar
    Dim X As Integer
    Dim dTotWidth As Double, dDayWidth As Double, dLeftStart As Double
    Dim dLeft As Double, dtop As Double, dWidth As Double, dHeight As Double
    Dim dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date, sName As String, sColor As String
    Dim myShape As Shape, dycwidth As Double, dRight As Double
    Dim Lastrow As Integer

    dLeftStart = Range("I2").Left
    X = 1
    
    'Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'With Range("G2:G" & Lastrow)
        '.Cells(Application.Match(WorksheetFunction.Min(.Cells), .Cells, 0), 1).Select
    'End With
    Range("G2").Select
    
   
    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        dDayWidth = DateDiff("d", ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value, ActiveCell.Value)
    'Baseline
        ' calculate top ...
        dtop = ActiveCell.Top + 3
    
    'calculate Left
        p = 9
        Do Until Month(Cells(1, p)) = Month(ActiveCell.Value) And _
        Year(Cells(1, p)) = Year(ActiveCell.Value) And _
        Day(Cells(1, p)) = Day(ActiveCell.Value)
        
        
        p = p + 1
        Loop
        dLeft = Cells(1, p).Left
        dLeft = dLeft + (dDayWidth * DateDiff("d", Cells(1, p), ActiveCell.Value))
    
        
        p = 9
        'calculate width ...
        Do Until Month(Cells(1, p)) = Month(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) And _
        Year(Cells(1, p)) = Year(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) And _
        Day(Cells(1, p)) = Day(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        
        
        
        p = p + 1
        Loop
        dRight = Cells(1, p).Left
        dRight = dRight + (dDayWidth * DateDiff("d", Cells(1, p), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value))
        dWidth = dRight - dLeft

        sName = "Scheduled" & X
        Call DynamicBox(dLeft, dtop, dWidth, 11, sName)
        
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select: X = X + 1
    Loop
    
End Sub

Sub DynamicBox(dLeft As Double, dtop As Double, dWidth As Double, dHeight As Double, sName As String)
Dim X As Double
 
    'reference to the 4 numbers left,top,width,height
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape _
 (msoShapeFlowchartProcess, dLeft, dtop, dWidth, dHeight).Select
 If InStr(sName, "Scheduled") > 0 Then
 Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
 Else
 Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 255)
 End If
 
 Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Solid
 Selection.ShapeRange.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
 Selection.Name = sName

End Sub
```

Any input on how to modify this code in order to correctly size and place the shapes would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Counting days between values of the same date:

```
DateDiff("d", Cells(1, p), ActiveCell.Value)
```

will always return zero. So, try counting minutes:

```
dRight = dRight + (dDayWidth * DateDiff("n", Cells(1, p), ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) / 3600)
```

Also, you *really* should read up on using *Range* objects to replace the clumsy and slow *Selection* and *ActiveCell*.